# Selecting a parametrized number of records (with repeater)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

Good day everyone,

so here, I have a problem with my repeater control's SQL query, what I would really want to happen, is I have a randomized number from 1 to 60, that will tell the database which test question to select, (if it's only one, it's not a problem, haha.) but then, I am required to display 20 questions from my database to the repeater control. my database also holds the 60 questions. So yeah, I tried some solutions in the net, but then my code always returns only one record, and it's quite a pain. Hope somebody could help me, I know to some it's quite basic, but I'm only a budding programmer, so yeah, thanks in advance.

btw, this is the chunk of code,

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i = 1;
    Random r = new Random();
        while (i <= 20)
        {
            int iss;
            string constr = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\thesis\WebSite8\App_Data\thesisDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
            string com = "SELECT * from CHAP1_quiz WHERE questionnumber = @num";
            SqlDataAdapter comms = new SqlDataAdapter();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(com, con);
            iss = r.Next(1, 60);
            comms.SelectCommand = cmd;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@num");
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            con.Open();
            comms.Fill(ds);
            Repeater1.DataSource = ds;
            Repeater1.DataBind();
            i++;;
            con.Close();
        }
}
```

oh yeah, let me tell you, when i run this code, it only displays 1 record. But I need 20, I know it's a lame question, but it's been bugging me for quite a while.

Comment: you are making a new dataset everytime i gets incremented. You are also binding to your repeater every loop your while goes through, that's why you only have 1 question. Store all of your questions in a List, then after your while loop bind that list to your repeater

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code would be in round trip 20 times in database, because each while loop you select one question, try to create `new DataSet` and bind data source again. That's why your list has just one question.

To avoid the round trip to database, instead of using random number and `while` loop in code, , get rid of `while` loop, you can use `SELECT` [random](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/466.cfm) in SQL by `ORDER BY NEWID()`

```
string constr = "...";
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

using (var con = new SqlConnection(constr))
{
    string sql = "SELECT TOP 20 * from CHAP1_quiz ORDER BY NEWID()";
    var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
    adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;

    con.Open();
    comms.Fill(ds);  
}

Repeater1.DataSource = ds;
Repeater1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the previous randon number in a array and send those numbers to sqlserver and use where condition as `WHERE questionnumber != arraynumber`